# Maven unable to find assertEquals symbol during maven install goal

Tags: java, maven, junit, assert, assertion

I am writing my test cases in my maven application, but during maven install goal, this is the error I am getting

```
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.506 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-11T12:45:21+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project registration-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /D:/OGOS-Swagger-App/RegistrationService/src/test/java/com/registration/ApiTest.java:[12,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Assert
[ERROR]   location: package org.junit
[ERROR] /D:/OGOS-Swagger-App/RegistrationService/src/test/java/com/registration/ApiTest.java:[12,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /D:/OGOS-Swagger-App/RegistrationService/src/test/java/com/registration/ApiTest.java:[34,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: class com.impetus.registration.ApiTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Please take a look into this error.
Below is my test class, for which I am getting the exception, the exception is the the assertEquals() part, although I have imported the Assert.assertEquals as static, but still there is error.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

class ApiTest {
    @Test
    void registrationTest() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        
        UserInput input = new UserInput();
        input.setAddress("Random");
        input.setEmail("xyz@xyz.com");
        input.setFirstName("First");
        input.setLastName("Last");
        input.setPhoneNo("9090909090");
        input.setPinCode("340901");
        input.setUserPassword("XXXXXXX");
        
        HttpEntity<UserInput> entity = new HttpEntity<UserInput>(input,headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:9901/register", HttpMethod.PUT,entity, String.class);
        String responseString = response.getBody();
        assertEquals("Registered",responseString);
    }
```

and this is pom file

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.2155</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;`

Comment: You're using org.junit.Assert which is from JUnit4 but your dependency is JUnit5. Try changing your import to org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals

Comment: Several things. First mixing spring boot parts with different versions. Parent spring boot version 2.5.1, spring-plugin-core with 2.0.0.RELEASE.. spring-boot-dev-tools 2.5.2 dependency to jdk.tools (really wrong!) Trying to use cobertura is old stuff. Use jacoco only ...Removed `sourceDirectory` if you follow conventions don't and configure things which are default.  Finally your code uses `import org.junit.*` which is JUnit 4 and not JUnit Jupiter...that's the issue.. Use the correct import for junit jupiter instead..

Comment: Thanks everyone, changing import from org.junit.Assert to org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong assert, try changing

`import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

to

`import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;`